# How can I delete session?

Tags: 8

I create `$_SESSION['loop'][$id]`.
When I unset `$id = 0` then all of `$_SESSION['loop']` are delete.
How can I do this?

```
$id = \Drupal::request()->query->get('id');

if (isset($_SESSION['loop']) & (isset($id)) & ( $_SESSION['loop'] > 0)) {
  $_SESSION['loop'] = $_SESSION['loop'] - 1;
  unset($_SESSION['label'][$id]);
  unset($_SESSION['code'][$id]);
  unset($_SESSION['price'][$id]);
  unset($_SESSION['sellercode'][$id]);
}

return header('Location: /basket');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this structure:

```
$_SESSION['mybasket'][$id] = [
  'label' => $label,
  'code' => $code,
  'price => $price,
];
```

Then you can delete one item

```
unset($_SESSION['mybasket'][$id]);
```

or the complete basket

```
unset($_SESSION['mybasket']);
```

You don't need the variable loop, to count the items use

```
$count = count($_SESSION['mybasket']);
```

Comment: Thanks.can I use this in table with for loop?Because I create a basket like ubercart.

Comment: `foreach ($_SESSION['mybasket'] as $id => $item)`

Comment: Thanks. One item is 
                $forms['table'][$loop]['TotalPrice'] = array(
                    '#markup' => number_format('0'),
                    '#wrapper_attributes' => array('id' => array('totalprice0')),
                );
How can I do this in your code ?

Comment: @SiMoNe Please stop harassing people by littering the site with comments asking for help in random questions. Ask a question, wait for a response. If you don't get one, improve the question, don't go around the site leaving comments everywhere